# PowerShell - How to add content to specific cell in CSV File

Tags: powershell, csv

I'd like to seek your help on how to add content to a specific cell in a CSV file that is already with populated data, here's an example of my CSV file:
[CSV File with populated data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlB8Y.png)

Here's an example of what I want to achieve:

| UPN | Skype? | TV? | Whiteboard? | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| room1 | true | true | true | Skype; TV; Whiteboard |
| room2 | true | false | false | Skype |
| room3 | false | true | true | TV; Whiteboard |

If `room1` has Skype, TV, and Whiteboard, then to create the description with these values. If any of these are false, skip them.
Does it make sense?

How can I achieve this using PowerShell?

This is what I've got so far:

```
Import-Csv $MeetingRooms | ForEach-Object {
    # Description field on Column Number 19
    $col = 19

    if ($_.Skype -eq $true) {
        $var = 'Skype for Business;'
        Add-Content -path $_ -Value "$(","*$col)$var"
    }elseif ($_.TV -eq $true) {
        $var = 'TV;'
        Add-Content -path $_ -Value "$(","*$col)$var"
    }elseif ($_.Whiteboard -eq $true) {
        $var = 'Whiteboard;'
        Add-Content -path $_ -Value "$(","*$col)$var"
    }
}
```

I am missing something big here which clearly can't see.

Thank you very much,
Gonzalo

Answer (score 1):

The following assumes that the column with index `19` is named `CurrentFacilities`.

```
Import-Csv $MeetingRooms | ForEach-Object {
  $obj = $_
  $obj.CurrentFacilities =
    ($obj.CurrentFacilities -split ';\s*') +
    ('Skype', 'TV', 'Whiteboard').Where({ $obj.$_ -eq 'true' }) -join '; '
  $obj # Output the modified object.
}
```